# Changing coordinate system of layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, layers, coordinates

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and I would like to change the coordinate system of a layer that is already attached to a drawing so that it matches the other layers.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this in-place. As Maksim says, you'll have to create a new feature class in the target coordinate system and add that to the map/drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Project (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000) tool. Input your layer, choose the coordinate system you would like it to be projected into.

Comment: The Define Projection tool may be necessary first (at which point on-the-fly projection should address the issue.  http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/08/23/when-to-use-the-define-projection-tool-and-the-project-tool-2/